# missing drive after installation of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I had widows before and I installed Ubuntu on it during installation I replace windows with Ubuntu right now I cannot see my D drive. And all the files which exited in D drive. 
what is the way to access this?

Comment: Have you tried to find the drive on Ubuntu Live environment DVD/USB? Please check if you can find it. Hope you didn't install Ubuntu on wrong drive or formatted the same by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Terminal and run

```
lsblk
```

the result would be something like below:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 531.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 117.2G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   466M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 384.4G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0  21.2G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

(If you see only sda1, that means your partition is formatted which means the chance for recovery is very low)

Based on the size of your D drive, you can find it here. I assume it is called `sda5`. Now we need to mount it for which we need a mount point. Make the mount point by running this command:

```
sudo mkdir /media/d
```

Now you have mount point. Mount your partition to it by running:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /media/d
```

If you get any error in any step, let me know.

Comment: when I run the first command it shows all my drive in one partition sda1

Comment: This literally means you have lost your partitions and most probably all data in them. Before doing anything else, you should go for doing recovery. Perhaps there is still some chance.